# Redirects in angular file

Tags: angularjs, solr, banana

Im a newbie to angular and trying to understand how the redirect works.

We are running a BANANA(SOLR) application and whenever the page is redirected to the pip.json file, the application generates a single page application using the JSON content given in the file.

banana/index.html#/dashboard/file/pip.json

Question:-

I don't see any folder dashboard/file within my application? What does dashboard/file mean after the '#' sign..

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the `#` symbol is Angular related. So in your example, `banana/index.html` will hit the server and respond with a request. The `#/dashboard/file/pip.json` will NOT hit the server and will be caught by Angular's routing.